# Tamil words which have vowels in the middle of the word

Tags: tamil

Is there any words in Tamil which have independent vowels in the middle of the word? If not why?

Tamil have special combined letters as "vowels + consonants" ("உயிர்மெய் எழுத்து"). But I couldn't find a word which is having only "vowels" standalone in the middle.  The independent vowels I am talking about.

Tamil vowels not appearing standalone other than first letter in word. It only comes associated with "consonants + vowels" ("உயிர்மெய் எழுத்து").

Comment: why down vote? is it useless question?

Comment: I'm asking the question in Tamil language. Not about English.

Comment: It seems not possible. I want to know whether any grammar behind this.

Comment: You question seems to be answered as "yes" in the Standalone Vowels section of https://r12a.github.io/scripts/tamil/  .  The example given is பெரீஇஇய

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are plenty. [Here](https://ilearntamil.com/tamil-words/) are some words of Tamil, which even gives a romanization. For instance *puthagam*, *vengaayam* where all of the vowels are in the middle (not at the beginning or the end). Some words have no vowels in the middle, for example *oli* (the only vowels are at the beginning or the end). If you mean *exact* middle, you'd have to define the unit of measurement. That might be "the exact center in a word in its conventional romanization, where the romanization has an odd number of letters" (e.g. *s**o**l*). We need a clearer definition of "middle" if this doesn't satisfy you.

Comment: Those are "உயிர்மெய் எழுத்து". So this is to find words which have "உயிர் எழுத்து". They ask this question for school child. Seems there is a grammer problem, which is not to have "உயிர் எழுத்து" alone in middle. Not sure about the grammer.

Comment: It is not exact middle. Tamil vowels not appearing standalone other than first letter. It only comes as  "உயிர்மெய் எழுத்து". Is it a grammer on tamil?